# Why do singular $0$-simplices have zero homology except on the $0$-singular homology group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplex

This should be easy but I am unfortunately struggling

**The setting**

Given a topological space $X$, let $\epsilon_i: \Delta^{n-1} \rightarrow \Delta^n$ be the $i$-th face map, where $\Delta^n$ is the standard $n$-simplex.

Let $\sigma_n: \Delta^n \rightarrow X$ be a singular $n$-simplex in $X$. We call $S_n(X)$ the free abelian group generated by the singular $n$-simplices in $X$, with the convention that $S_{-1}(X)=0$.

The boundary of a $\sigma_k$ is defined as
$$\delta_n(\sigma_k) = \sum_{i = 0}^n (-1)^i \sigma_k \circ \epsilon_i $$

($\delta_n(\sigma_k) : S_n(X) \rightarrow S_{n-1}(X)$) and the $n$-singular homology group is given by  $\ker( \delta_n) / \text{img}(\delta_{n+1})$.

**The question**

I want to know why do singular $0$-simplices have zero homology except on the  $0$-singular homology group.

**My attempt**

The $0$-singular homology group is $\ker( \delta_0) / \text{img}(\delta_{1})$, the $\ker( \delta_0)$ is all the singular $0$-simplices while $$\delta_1(\sigma_0) = \sigma_0 \circ\epsilon_0 - \sigma_0 \circ\epsilon_1 = ?$$
Ideally I would like $\sigma_0 \circ\epsilon_0 - \sigma_0 \circ\epsilon_1$ to cancel since then the homology group is not only zero but it would be formed by all the  singular $0$-simplices ( I am assuming that "having zero homology"  means that the homology group is just the zero element, correct?). 
But why would it cancel?

It seems to me that $\sigma_0 \circ\epsilon_1$ is not even well defined.

Moreover I would like to show than for the other homology groups the 
singular $0$-simplices have zero homology but since I am having so many problems understanding the zeroth case I will stop here.

Comment: why do you calculate the first boundary of a 0-simplex $\sigma_0$ should that rather be $\delta_1\sigma_1$, $\sigma_1$ being a 1-simplex?

Comment: you should check out Bredon's topology an Geometry chapter "the zeroth homology group"

Comment: @VanillaThunder actually I am unsure how to proceed there exactly, I will check out your recommendation, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "singular $0$-simplices"?  By its usual meaning, "singular $0$-simplices" is not something that you can take the homology of.  What chain complex are you taking the homology of, exactly?

Comment: @EricWofsey I think this is the root of the problem, I had misunderstood the question posed to me.